# Does "origins" mean some kind of historical information here? Why it uses the plural?

Tags: meaning

Transformers:

> Cybertron existed, from metallic surface to core, as a vast Saturn-sized machine world... a world whose origins were lost in the dead past.

cambridge dictionary gives this definition about origin

> the beginning or cause of something

and this example

> It's a book about the origin of the universe.

Does "origins" mean some historical information here? Why it uses the plural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means the *historical beginnings* of the machine world Cybertron were unknown.

It is idiomatic to talk of “origins” in the plural like this for large complex things like cities, nations, cultures and historical trends. The same is true of “beginnings” for that matter. For example:

> The rise of the Roman Empire, from its **origins** as a small city-state
>   to its conquest of a vast empire...
>
> The mythic and historical **beginnings** of the city [of Vilnius] coincide with the **beginnings** of the Lithuanian state and the Lithuanian people.

I suppose this is because there are many triggers and inputs involved in beginning complex things like empires and vast machine cities - not just one event or cause.

*But remember:* presumed explanations like this don’t really matter with idiom - it’s just what native speakers say.

Comment: You didn't explicitly call attention to it, but we often pluralise ***beginnings*** (and ***roots***) as well as ***origins***. But I can't think of any similar terms that we might pluralise in this way for the *specific* intended sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica.  Funny I didn’t even see that despite using “beginnings” myself. I have edited it, thank you. It may be different with “roots” as, for a tree and then figuratively, it seems a more ordinary plural (in fact that may even be the etymological origin of, or at least an influence upon, the related plurals).

Comment: I must just say that from my point of view, the "star of the show" in your answer is actually that final caveat. We can hypothesize various *explanations* for why we're happy to pluralise *some* (but not *all*) "synonyms" for ***inception, genesis*** - but until we're asked to address the issue on something like this ELL question, most of us native speakers won't have given it any thought whatsoever. We're just repeating the forms we've become accustomed to, after hearing them from *other* native speakers.